# web application cart implementation for non-logged users

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, session, jhipster

I am working for implementing a spring-boot based shopping application, where a feature exist called ‘add to cart’ for product which works when users is only logged in. Meaning spring-boot back-end creates session when user logged in to make mapping to cart object.

I am trying to implementing a features like real world shopping application like amazon, where product can be added into ‘cart’ even user is not logged in. Then after user log-in user session can be managed / merged with previous non-logged user.

Can some please give me any typical design pattern idea in details or book reference or tutorial link where I can get details idea about such kind of implementation.

Comment: Not really a JHipster question

Comment: actually the implementation is based on jhipster, that's why I mentioned jhipster tag

Answer (score 2):

If user is anonymous, I would save cart on server and save cart ID in browser using a persistent cookie. When user logs in, server can retrieve the anonymous cart from its ID. Alternatively, you could store full cart in cookie.